# How to host parallel Oauth client and verification cells in Jupyter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth, oauth-2.0, ipython

To work with some data API (FB/VK/Google+ for example) I need an oAuth token that site can send to my app. I have created an app. Yet I want just to check it out for now. So I have an IPython\Jupyter notebook. I want to perform an Oauth Client\Verification authentification and get a token for my future use all within a notebook.

How to host a oAuth verification server in one cell and call an authentification mechanism (oAuth client) in the other one all inside one notebook?